# Error al pasar un array de NumPy a una función

Tags: python, numpy, array

Tengo definida una función en Python que funciona correctamente para valores escalares:

```
>>> def signo(x):
...   if x < 0:
...     return -1
...   elif x > 0:
...     return 1
...   else:
...     return 0
...
>>> signo(10)
1
>>> signo(-5)
-1
```

Pero cuando le paso un array de NumPy, falla con un `ValueError`:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> t = np.arange(-5, 5)
>>> t
array([-5, -4, -3, -2, -1,  0,  1,  2,  3,  4])
>>> signo(t)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in signo
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

¿Por qué sucede esto?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

En este caso el mensaje de error explica claramente el problema: "el valor de verdad de un array de más de un elemento es ambiguo". En el momento en que Python tiene que evaluar este condicional:

```
if x < 0:  # x es ahora array([-5, -4, -3, -2, -1,  0,  1,  2,  3,  4])
```

no puede devolver ni `True` ni `False`, porque hay elementos del array que cumplen la condición y elementos que no la cumplen. Este es un problema muy típico.

*Suponiendo que queramos otro array, del mismo tamaño que el de entrada, con valores `True` o `False` dependiendo de si el elemento correspondiente cumple o no la condición*, habría dos maneras de resolverlo:

1) Implementar toda la lógica internamente: habría que evaluarla en bucle para cada uno de los elementos del array. Una implementación sería esta:

```
>>> def signo(x):
...   x = np.atleast_1d(x)  # Convertimos a array
...   sgn = np.zeros_like(x)
...   for ii in range(len(sgn)):
...     if x[ii] < 0:
...       sgn[ii] = -1
...     elif x[ii] > 0:
...       sgn[ii] = 1
...     else:
...       pass  # sgn[ii] ya vale 0
...   return sgn
...
>>> signo(10)
array([1])
>>> signo(-5)
array([-1])
>>> signo(t)
array([-1, -1, -1, -1, -1,  0,  1,  1,  1,  1])
```

2) **Vectorizar** la función, utilizando `np.vectorize`. Nótese que así el caso escalar se gestiona de forma más elegante:

```
>>> def signo(x):
...   if x < 0:
...     return -1
...   elif x > 0:
...     return 1
...   else:
...     return 0
...
>>> signo = np.vectorize(signo)  # Vectorizamos la función
>>> signo(10)
array(1)
>>> signo(-5)
array(-1)
>>> signo(t)
array([-1, -1, -1, -1, -1,  0,  1,  1,  1,  1])
```

En este problema concreto la recomendación de usar `.any()` o `.all()` no sirve, pero en otra ocasión pueden ser funciones útiles.