# Error al intentar calcular elemento con mayor valor de un array

Tags: python, array, python-3.x, numpy

Tengo un problema con la siguiente función:

```
def conjunmas():
    for (conjunto) in (arreglo):
        totalm = 0
        cma = 0        
        for (unidad) in (arreglo):
            totalm = (totalm + unidad)
            if (totalm > cma):
                cma = totalm

    print(cma)
```

Al hacer la prueba me da el siguiente error:

> ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is
>   ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Agradezco me indiquen el problema, y si estoy empleando bien el código.

Comment: Con que valores hiciste la prueba?

Comment: Dejando tu función aparte si quieres saber cual es el mayor valor de una lista, puedes usar `max()`.

Comment: Utilice un archivo.txt que contiene los siguientes valores: 21 23 25 50 20 
35 22 35 38 30
41 42 43 25 22
35 22 42 22 25
16 15 16 10 20  
11 12 15 19 10

Comment: Como accedes al archivo txt? Haz probado con una lista sencilla a ver si te arroja el mismo error?

Comment: archivo= open("Archivo/ventas.txt","r")
arreglo=np.zeros(shape=(columnas,filas))
fila=0
for(linea) in (archivo):
    elementos=linea.split()
    arreglo[fila]=elementos
    fila=fila+1
    archivo.close

Comment: cual es el valor de las variables columnas y filas?

Comment: (Columnas=6, Filas=5), acabo de probar el comando max() y parece funcionar, gracias! no lo conocia.

Comment: Trata de agregar mas código y un poco de contexto a tu pregunta (editala) para ayudarte mejor porque no he podido reproducir tu error.

Comment: Relacionada: http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/285/error-al-pasar-un-array-de-numpy-a-una-funci%C3%B3n

Comment: Si usas `numpy` puedes usar directamente `arr = np.loadtxt("Archivo/ventas.txt")` y luego hacer `arr.reshape(6, 5)`. Además, ahora podrás acceder al máximo del array usando un método `arr.max()`

Answer (score 1):

El tema de numpy.all() o .any() suele saltar cuando comparamos directamente una matriz de numpy contra otra matriz en un statement ya que no puede sacar una unica respuesta para la iteracion de todos los elementos de la matriz

Lo que viene a decir es que al comparar una matriz, el decir "mayor que" o "menor que" es ambiguo, ya que se compone de una "lista" de una o mas dimensiones, y para ello ... numpy facilita el .all() y .any() , que viene a decir si quieres comparar todos los valores del eje indicado o que el statement sea para cualquier elemento iterado en el eje.
Para muestra un boton:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])  # Vector 1d
b = np.array([[0,0,0,0,0],[6,6,6,6,6]])  # Matriz 2d
c = np.array([[1,1,1,1,1],[3,7,0,0,8]]) # Otra Matriz de 2d
```

Si comparasemos directamente unas con otras:

```
a < b
Out[4]: array([[False, False, False, False, False], [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True]], dtype=bool)
b < a
Out[5]: array([[ True,  True,  True,  True,  True], [False, False, False, False, False]], dtype=bool)
c > b
Out[7]:array([[ True,  True,  True,  True,  True], [False,  True, False, False,  True]], dtype=bool)
```

Como vemos en la ultima comparacion nos da un bool por cada elemento ya que hemos comparado todos, pero ,  si decimos if c > b esperando un True o False  numpy no sabe a que nos estamos refiriendo ya que la declaracion es ambigua.

```
if c > b:
    print('mayor')

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\envs\py3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2881, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-12-9893a7236442>", line 1, in <module>
    if c > b:
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

los .all() y .any() nos devuelven True si todos los valores son True, en caso del all o si alguno es True en caso del any.

```
d = np.array([True,False,False,True,True])
d.all()
False
d.any()
True
```

Que para los casos comparativos del principio podrian ser:

```
d.any()>c.all()
True
# que seria lo mismo que True > False
```

o

```
(c > b).any()
True
(c > b).all()
False
```

Que seria el caso de aplicar .all .any a la matriz resultado de las primeras comparaciones de c>b espero haber sido de ayuda.
La documentacion de numpy para estos dos metodos donde explican bastante mejor que yo lo que hacen teneis en:

[numpy.any()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.any.html)

[numpy.all()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.all.html)